# how to complete firebase signup authentication if network interruptions take place

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase as my backend. In my project during signing up process, the users email address is stored first and then the profile photo uploads. But sometimes if there are network interruptions after firebase registers the users email (and my app returns an error), the profile photo doesn't uploads.
Meanwhile when user retries to sign up , it says email address already in use.

I tried `Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: nil)` after error to clear up the user email address so that the user can sign up again but
may be its not the best practice, So 
is there any other way.
Also can we upload it when the app regains connectivity?
Code for the signup view controller:

```
 guard emailAddress.text != "" , password.text != "" , fullName.text != ""
        else {
            errorOutlet.isHidden = false
            errorOutlet.text = "one or more fields are empty."
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            return SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }

    if password.text != "" , emailAddress.text != "" , fullName.text != "" {
   Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailAddress.text! , password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
            switch errCode {

            case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "The email you entered is already in use"

            case .invalidEmail:
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "The Email you entered is invalid"

            case .internalError:
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "An internal error occured! Try again."

            case .networkError:
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "Check your internet connection."

            case .weakPassword :
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "Your password should contain more than 7 characters"

            default : break

            }
        }
    }



    // the auth returns a user
    if let user = user {

        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser!.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest.displayName = self.fullName.text!
        changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: nil)

        let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImage.image!, 0.5)
        let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data! , metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)

                //error


                Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: nil)
                self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                self.errorOutlet.text = "An error occured. Try again!"
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

            }


            imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url , er) in
                // in case of error
                if er != nil{
                    print(er!.localizedDescription)
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: nil)
                    self.errorOutlet.isHidden = false
                    self.errorOutlet.text = "An error occured. Try again!"
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                }
```